# Divergence for Bhattacharya Information matrix

Tags: st.statistics, it.information-theory, entropy, information-geometry

The Fisher information matrix (in the scalar parameter case) can be obtained from the Kullback-Leibler divergence by

$$g(\theta) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta'}D(p_\theta\|p_{\theta'})\Bigg|_{\theta'=\theta},$$
where
$$D(p_\theta\|p_\theta') = \int p_\theta(x)\log\frac{p_\theta(x)}{p_{\theta'}(x)}.$$

I would like to know if the analogous information matrix in the [Bhattacharya bound](http://epgp.inflibnet.ac.in/epgpdata/uploads/epgp_content/statistics/03._statistical_inference_i___/02._cramer_rao_lower_bounds/et/9510_et_module-16.pdf) (the matrix $V_K$) can also be obtained from a divergent function. Any help in this connection is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please clarify "divergent function". I took it to mean some kind of information divergence.

Comment: @kodlu: Yes, by a 'divergence function', I mean an information divergence such as 'Kullback_leibler divergence'. However, I would like to derive the information matrix in the Bhattacharya bound from it.